# Using ViewerJS with Django

Tags: python, django, pdf, django-staticfiles, pdf.js

I am trying to use [ViewerJS](http://viewerjs.org/) in a Django 1.8.2 application. However, the link I am using will not render the PDF. I have the ViewerJS folder under `static/js/` and my PDF under `static/pdf/docs/`. Here is the link I'm using:

```
<a href="/static/js/ViewerJS/#/static/pdf/docs/agreement.pdf" class="btn">Preview</a>
```

The error I am receiving is a 404. Django passes back an error message "Directory indexes are not allowed here.".

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/static/js/ViewerJS/
Raised by:  django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve
```

If I go to `localhost:8000/static/pdf/docs/agreement.pdf` in my browser then the PDF downloads just fine. If I go to `localhost:8000/static/js/ViewerJS/pdf.js` then the pdf.js file downloads just fine. So I'm not sure why it isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django's static server is *only for development*, and is purposely limited. As the error says, it doesn't deal with directory indexes.

You could probably make this work by making the link go directly to `/static/js/ViewerJS/index.html`.

Comment: Ooh, that makes sense! I thought the `index.html` page was just an example page you download with ViewerJS. When I included index.html on the URL it worked just fine. Thanks a lot! I'll accept your answer in a few minutes (SO won't let me yet).

Answer (score 0):

I have just the same problem. I am trying to access a file located at static/gutenberg/docs/files/something.pdf in Django

The url I created is

"http://localhost:8000/static/gutenberg/js/ViewerJS/index.html/#/static/gutenberg/docs/files/something.pdf".

Inspite of adding index.html to the complete it wouldn't work.I am not sure why.

The path is right because I am able to download the file when I run "/static/gutenberg/docs/files/something.pdf" on my browser.